# Edit/View Tab in Region other than Content

Tags: theming

I'm trying to set up two contexts for use with a sub-theme of Omega.

3 Column Context:
Uses the regions Sidebar First, Content and Sidebar Second. Content is 6 columns wide. The Sidebar regions are each 3 columns wide. This works fine.

2 Column Context
Uses "Content Second" (9 cols. wide) and Sidebar Second (3 cols. wide).

Content Second is an additional region added to the info file in the sub-theme. 
regions[content_2] = Content Second

The problem that I'm having is getting the Edit/View tabs to display in that region, the way they do with region "Content".

I've added region--content_2.tpl.php to my sub-themes folder which seems to be working but when I add:

```
<?php if ($tabs && !empty($tabs['#primary'])): ?><div class="tabs clearfix"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

I get a "Notice: Undefined variable: tabs in include() " refering to that code.

Is it possible to get the Edit/View tabs in any region other than "Content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Delta Blocks module which is included in omega. It moves these tabs (and other things like Messages) into blocks.

Comment: Thanks very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!